# NSPredicate filter by letter

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do you make an NSPredicate that finds all objects in an array that contain a certain letters?

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"abc",@"cba", @"bca", nil];

NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",@"abc"];

NSMutableArray *result = (NSMutableArray *)[testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: p];
```

Result only contains one object, @"abc"... I want it to catch all words that have "abc" in them. (e.g "cba", "cba", "lllllllllbbacllllll" etc)..

Comment: `result` is **not** a mutable array. `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` always returns an instance of `NSArray`, not of `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: This case you should write [[testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: p] mutableCopy];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the other answers. However, I wanted to suggest a different way to create the predicate: using a block.

```
NSArray *testArray = @[@"abc", @"cba", @"cda"];
NSArray *letters = @[@"a", @"b", @"c"];

NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id string, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    for ( NSString *letter in letters ) {
        NSStringCompareOptions options = NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch;
        if ( ! [string rangeOfString:letter options:options].length ) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}];
NSArray *result = [testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

And just for the fun, you can also write the predicate with a subquery. This is less efficient but it's the shorter solution.

```
NSArray *testArray = @[@"abc", @"cba", @"bcda"];
NSArray *letters = @[@"a", @"b", @"c"];

NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(%@, $a, self CONTAINS[cd] $a)[SIZE] == %d", letters, letters.count];
NSArray *result = [testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it possible to get all the words from the "testArray" even if some of the "letters" isn't in there. So If I add @"d", to the letters, it would still find "abc" in the testArray?

Comment: If you accept words that don't contain all the required letters, then what are the words that should be excluded?

Comment: I just the words (In testArray) that can be constructed with the "letters". I will later validate each and every word, which takes a lot of performance. So i figure I remove all the words that can't be constructed with the letters first

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's possible with a single predicate, but you can build a compound predicate using `NSCompoundPredicate`:

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"abc",@"cba", @"bca", nil];

NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *substring in @[@"a", @"b", @"c"]) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", substring];
    [predicates addObject:predicate];
}
NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];

NSArray *result = [testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate];
```

Please also see Nicolas's comment on `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`.

Comment: Thanks. It works great. However, once I got this to work, I figure out I need one more thing. If I add @"b" to the substring letters (So the predicate contains "a,b,c,d", I wont get a matches. Basically, what I want to do is input a bunch of random letters, and then filter the array for all possible words that those letters can create.

Answer (score 1):

Test the characters singularly, give this a shot:

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"abc",@"cba", @"bca", nil];
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains 'a' && self contains 'b' && self contains 'c'"];
NSMutableArray *result = [[testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: p] mutableCopy];
```